# can't upgrade pip to 9.0.1 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-2.7, pip, upgrade

I tried the following command so many times without luck:

```
sudo -H pip install -U pip
```

Here is the output:

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

My pip is still at version 8.1.1

```
pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

What is going on? Why the upgrade option didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install` installs everything into `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`.

Your new pip is now `/usr/local/bin/pip`. Add `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in your PATH and verify that the new pip is being run with `pip --version`.

*Upd*. We finally found the culprit of the problem — `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy-install.pth` contains wrong line `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. Remove it.

Comment: both pip in `/usr/bin/pip` and `/usr/local/bin/pip` give me the same version 8.1.1. Also, from the output of the upgrade, it looks like version 9.0.1 was not installed.

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/pip --version` show
`pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` or `pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`? (Mine is the 1st). Is there `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip`? (Must be after `sudo pip install -U pip`) Run `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` — is `'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'` in the list? What is the output of `python -c "import pip; print pip.__file__"`? (Mine is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.pyc`)

Comment: I see what you mean here. Apparently pip 9.0.1 was installed at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, but `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` containing pip8.1.1 is on top of the sys.path. Now I can get pip 9.0.1 inside python by inserting `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` on top of the sys.path. However, I still cannot get pip9.0.1 on terminal since both `/usr/bin/pip` and `/usr/local/bin/pip` are of version 8.1.1. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Output of `/usr/local/bin/pip --version` is `pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

Comment: pip8.1.1 at `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` is normal. `pip` installs new pip in `/usr/local` bit doesn't uninstall system pip. To use the new pip `sys.path` in Python must have `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` before `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. For me this is the default. In case if it's not the same in your case you should rearrange `sys.path` manually. Use `PYTHONPATH`, e.g., or something else; e.g. run `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages python -m pip…`

Comment: I can run pip 9.0.1 within python by adding the correct path on top of sys.path. However I want to run `sudo -H pip install -U pip`. Can you show me how to invoke pip9.0.1 within that command?

Comment: `sudo -H PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages pip install -U pip`

Comment: Opps, sorry @phd that is not what I mean. What I want is to use pip under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` as the default pip in search path. So I need to somehow update $PATH instead of PYTHONPATH. However there is no executable pip under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` .

Comment: The executable is `/usr/local/bin/pip`, so prepend `/usr/local/bin` to PATH.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. Check my earlier comment (4th from top) you will see `/usr/local/bin/pip` is pip 8.1.1

Comment: Yep, I remember. That's actually your main problem. As I've said already, I need to change `sys.path` so that `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` goes before `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. For me this is the default, I don't know why it's not for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152791/discussion-between-tu-bui-and-phd).